# Is there a way to apply multiple column based conditional formatting in angular when using ngFOR in td with columns names coming from a variable?

Tags: html, css, angular, conditional-formatting

I am faced with a problem in my angular project. I am using one variable i.e. **csvColumnHeaders** for my column names as few column names keep changing. The rest column names are static.

My data variable object is **vfyieldInfo**.

I am using **yield[column]** in a ngfor loop to display my data for each column.

Question: I want to apply conditional color formatting on one fixed name column based on another fixed name column. How can I do that since I dont have separate  for each column ?

```
<table class="table table-bordered" align="center">
  <thead>
  <tr align="center" class="myHeaderClass">
    <th
      *ngFor="let column of csvColumnHeaders"
      scope="col"
      class="headerGrey"
    >
      {{ column }}
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr align="center" *ngFor="let yield of vfyieldInfo">
    <td *ngFor="let column of csvColumnHeaders">
      <p class="{{ column }}">{{ yield[column] }}</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks
Ankit

I am expecting to apply multiple column based conditional formatting. however I am not able to apply it since I dont have separate  entries for each column. The reason behind that is that I am using a variable object for column names since few column names keep changing.

I want to apply conditional formatting on the columns whose names dont change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngStyle` for support conditional case.

**Example**

```
<td *ngFor="let column of csvColumnHeaders" 
    [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (column=='id') ? 'black' : 'white'}">
  <p class="{{ column }}">{{ yield[column] }}</p>
</td>
```

Ref: [Document](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)